# Enabling orbtControls depending on the camera used

Tags: three.js, rendering

I'm working on a project in **THREE.js** that involves the use of two cameras for the same scene that can be alternated by pressing a keyboard button.
A flag changes its value between 0 and 1 depending of which camera is in use.

The question is: How can I enable `orbitControls` in just one of the two cameras, disabling it when that camera is not in use?

Comment: "disabling it when that camera is not in use" can you explain this 
Probably you can toggle flag  controls.update()  this what you mean.???

Comment: well,basically,I want to associate the orbitControls to the second camera and not to the first.The thing is,I don't know how to make orbitControls for just one of the two cameras leaving the other without them.

Comment: this way of toggle is helpful ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239892/three-js-orbit-controls-with-two-toggled-cameras/36241045#36241045

Comment: I saw that solution and I tried it too,but it gives me a TypeError,telling me that this.object is undefined