# Issue with orbit controls and effect composer

Tags: three.js

I'm Gabriele and I'm new in three.js world, I have an issue with a code, my orbitcontrols were works good, but when I added the composer to make the scene blurred they stopped working... Google's Console (in the browser) don't show me any error, so I don't know what happening to the code. I declared every js that I used in the code.

Somebody can help me please?

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.dispose();
controls.update();
controls.reset();

    composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);

    renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
    composer.addPass(renderPass);

     horizontalBlur = new THREE.ShaderPass({
        ...THREE.HorizontalBlurShader,
            uniforms: {
        ...THREE.HorizontalBlurShader.uniforms,
      h: {value: 1.0 / window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio},
    },
  })
 composer.addPass(horizontalBlur)

  verticalBlur = new THREE.ShaderPass({
        ...THREE.VerticalBlurShader,
             uniforms: {
        ...THREE.VerticalBlurShader.uniforms,
      v: {value: 1.0 / window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio },
    },
  })
  composer.addPass(verticalBlur)
}
```

Comment: I'm working on a web app which needs swtching between ortho and perspective camera & the outlinePass & Orbit controls. These 3 in combination is causing a similar issue, I haven't been able to solve it yet. Tried [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368753/6908282) by @Mugen87, but it didn't help. Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239892/6908282) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36339796/6908282) similar the issue that I'm facing

Answer (score 1):

```js
controls.dispose();
controls.update();
controls.reset();
```

There is no need to call these methods. Especially calling `dispose()` is problematic since this method will remove all event listeners of `OrbitControls`. Just do this and try again:

```js
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

In general, the usage of `EffectComposer` should not affect controls in any form.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply, now it work, but I set the orbitcontrol to follow the cursor point but this don't work, it work only if I drag or if I zoom in with the wheel of the mouse. Before adding the composer were work, now don't work.

Comment: Can you please share a live example that demonstrates the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: K, I did it, but now it show an error of orbit control. https://jsfiddle.net/o1rzs43j/

Comment: The URL to `OrbitControls` was incorrect. Try it with: https://jsfiddle.net/tro4xvhp/